# How to escape @ symbol in jsdoc for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When writing jsDoc, if it contains an `@` symbol, it throws off VSCode.

How can the symbol be escaped?

I do not want to use the HTML escape code `&#64;` because it is not rendered as `@` inside codeblocks.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the complete text of the this code snippet?

Comment: don't post images of code, show the actual code for `filter`

Comment: I have tried many different constructs but could not find a way to write a literal @, also the JSDoc docs don't mention it

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've found to work is backticks:

```js
/**
 * @param {type} myVal My val with `@` in the description
 */
```

That stops the parser from adding line breaks but does make the @ render as  fixed width.

Comment: It also puts a space before and after the `@` leading to a result like: `foo @ bar`

Comment: Ahh fair.  I don't mind it (and actually want the spaces) for my usecase.  Maybe file an issue on the VS Code GitHub page?